# How to make custom sounds resource packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm creating a minigame where I use a resource pack with custom sounds, but they changed the sound engine in 1.9, and I don't know how to do that any more. I can already use `/playsound`, I just can't figure out how to add my own sounds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add sounds to a resource pack, not replace them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361803/add-sounds-to-a-resource-pack-not-replace-them)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by replacing the old music/sound file with your own. Make a quick search for .ogg (or something like that) sounds to find the folder(s). Then, replace some music disk sounds with yours. Also, but I'm not so sure about that, you could add a new sound file to the system and try to play it.

Comment: @RudolfJenlinek The thing is I want to have tons and tons of sounds, and there aren't enough replaceable sounds do do that. I know there is a way to add more, I just don't know how.

Comment: @Sam54123 I think that if you add a new sound file NEXT to the existing ones, the /playsound will maybe work :D

Comment: @RuldolfJeninek I know the way to do it is to make a sounds.json file, but I don't know the correct formating.

Comment: @Sam54123 OK (-: At least I tried :D