# Minecraft - add custom painting via resource pack without replacing existing texture

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm trying to *add* a custom painting to Minecraft Java edition in a custom resource pack. I do *not* want to replace one of the existing painting textures provided with the games.

I tried to put an image (as a PNG) in the `/assets/mynamespace/textures/painting/mypainting.png` directory of my resource pack and then use the texture for an existing painting by running `/data modify entity @e[type=painting,limit=1,sort=nearest] variant set value "mynamespace:mypainting"`, but this did not work. The painting simply changed to the `minecraft:kebab` variant. **How can I add a custom painting to Minecraft with a resource pack without replacing an existing texture?**

As an example, how can I get this image:
[image]
as a painting by using a resource pack?  It is acceptable (and perhaps even preferable) if this is only possible if a command is issued in-game.

---

### Related

I'm basically looking for something like this [Add sounds to a resource pack, not replace them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361803) but for paintings instead of sounds.

Comment: It doesn't work just like that. But maybe something with custom block models is possible that can be integrated into a data pack that makes it behave like a painting.