# how to add custom sounds in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i've been making my own resource pack from scratch. the problem is. I want fire to sound more horrorific. I searched other questions. but they told me to go to `PACK\assets\Minecraft\SOUNDS`. I cant find the 'sounds' in the first place can anyone help me?

Comment: :/ i want to add it into specificly my RESOURCE PACK

Comment: and this is 1.16.3 minecraft not anything under

Comment: You'll need to create the `PACK/assets/Minecraft/sounds` folder yourself.

Comment: makes sense, thx :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom sounds resource packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265790/how-to-make-custom-sounds-resource-packs)